# Measure as SUM with Min/Max Value of Another Column as Condition

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to get a sum of one column based on the date in another.

| Count | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 05/01/2021 |
| 200 | 05/01/2021 |
| 300 | 05/01/2021 |
| 100 | 06/01/2021 |
| 200 | 06/01/2021 |
| 400 | 06/01/2021 |
| 100 | 07/01/2021 |
| 300 | 07/01/2021 |
| 500 | 07/01/2021 |

In SQL what I want is:
`SELECT SUM([COUNT]) WHERE [Date] = MIN([Date]) FROM [rpt_data]`

I can't figure out how to do this in DAX.  I tried:
`CALCULATE( SUM([Count]), MIN([Date]) )`
But it says that I can't use MIN as a filter.
I know this works: `CALCULATE( SUM([Count]), rpt_data[Date] = "07/01/2021" )`  But I need to know the first and last dates dynamically.

I need another with MAX[Date]) but I figure if I get one figured out I'll figure out the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the engine doesn't know what do you want. We need to show which column we want to compare with a date. Example:

```
measure =
var __minDate = calculate( min(OrderTable[Date]))
return
CALCULATE( SUM(SalesTable[Count]), FILTER(ALL(SalesTable[Date]), SalesTable[Date] = __minDate)
```

Comment: Perfect thank you!
I was just trying to create a measure that's the min value and use that as a filter, but it didn't like that either.  I'm going to take some time to unpack your answer so I know how to apply it in the future!